# Advanced text editor for LESS?

Tags: text-editor, css, less

I am currently using Crunch as my primary LESS-Editor. It offers syntax highlighting and folding which helps. But I wonder if there are editors that leverage the full functionality of LESS.

For example some traditional CSS editors enlisted the CSS selectors in the file. But in LESS classes can be nested, so a tree view would be needed.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

**SynWrite** (Windows) is LESS aware. Supports LESS hiliting, and nested { } blocks, and tree view for blocks.

[image: LESS]

Comment: The Tree Structure feature is nice, but from my first impression it's a very generic editor with no "specific" less support. I havn't found an integrated to-CSS compiler and the auto-complete is also very generic. E.g. it won't recognize defined variables and show them